# Critical dependency Mapbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, mapbox

I installed `@mapbox/search-js-core` into my nextJS app, so that I could use the autocomplete search function and the plugin started throwing this error which crashed my nextjs app.

```
@mapbox/search-js-core/dist/index-esm.js
Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
```

The code

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { AddressAutofill } from '@mapbox/search-js-react';
 
export default class Details extends React.Component {
render(){
return (
    <form>
    <AddressAutofill accessToken="my-access-token-here">
    <input
    name="address" placeholder="Address" type="text"
    autoComplete="address-line1"
    />
    </AddressAutofill>
    <input
    name="apartment" placeholder="Apartment number" type="text"
    autoComplete="address-line2"
    />
    <input
    name="city" placeholder="City" type="text"
    autoComplete="address-level2"
    />
    <input
    name="state" placeholder="State" type="text"
    autoComplete="address-level1"
    />
    <input
    name="country" placeholder="Country" type="text"
    autoComplete="country"
    />
    <input
    name="postcode" placeholder="Postcode" type="text"
    autoComplete="postal-code"
    />
    </form>
);
}
}
```

this code is also the same code on Mapbox website that says how to use this plugin for reactJS apps - I am wondering is this a nextjs issue or react issue?

package.json - before adding mapbox dependancy.

```
{
  "name": "goadstichr",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@next-auth/mongodb-adapter": "^1.0.3",
    "@turf/circle": "^6.5.0",
    "@turf/turf": "^6.5.0",
    "airwallex-payment-elements": "^0.2.79",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "bootstrap-daterangepicker": "^3.1.0",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "d3-request": "^1.0.6",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "formidable": "^2.0.1",
    "gridfs-stream": "^1.1.1",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "mapbox-gl": "^2.8.2",
    "micro": "^9.3.4",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "mongodb": "^4.5.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.3.5",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "multer-gridfs-storage": "^5.0.2",
    "multiparty": "^4.2.3",
    "next": "12.1.5",
    "next-auth": "^4.3.1",
    "next-connect": "^0.12.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.3.1",
    "react-bootstrap-daterangepicker": "^7.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-map-gl": "^7.0.12",
    "recharts": "^2.1.10",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.4.17",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.13.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.1.5"
  }
}
```

and next.config

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Comment: I added your code to a codesandbox and everything seems to work fine except auth token- https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-grass-klfqp0?file=/src/App.js - Post your code in a similar environment including your package.json, next.config etc. visisble.

Comment: @Ramakay added both next.config and package.json

Comment: if this is still occuring, i guess you could try `overrides` (npm) or `resolutions` (yarn) to pin `search-js-core: x.x.x` dependency in package.json

Comment: I am not seeing any dependencies listed in the `package.json` for `search-js-core` - In my codesandbox, https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-grass-klfqp0?file=/package.json:187-235 you can see an explicit declaration of `    "@mapbox/search-js-react": "1.0.0-beta.11",` - perhaps to try explicitly listing and then `yarn` or doing another install.